# Change array keys to a value within the array

Tags: php

**Edit:**

Trying to avoid doing a loop outside of the `$data` array you see. As I need to do this a couple of times and it looks messy.

---

I have got an array similar to this:

```
$links = [
    [
        'type_id' => '1',
        'url' => ''
    ],
    [
        'type_id' => '2',
        'url' => ''
    ]
];
$types = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'value' => 'facebook'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2
        'value' => 'twitter'
    ]
];
$data = [
    'primary' => [
        'address_details' => [],
        'contact_details' => [],
        'social_links' => $links
    ]
];
```

I need the keys within my `$data['primary']['social_links']` to use the `$type['value']` rather than just being 0, 1, etc...

So `$data` would look like:

```
$data = [
    'primary' => [
        'address_details' => [],
        'contact_details' => [],
        'social_links' => [
            'facebook' => [
                'type_id' => '1',
                'url' => ''
            ],
            'twitter' => [
                'type_id' => '2',
                'url' => ''
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Is there a way I can do this with `array_map` or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) with the output of the `value` column of `$types` (generated using [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)) as keys and the values from `$links`:

```
$data = [
    'primary' => [
        'address_details' => [],
        'contact_details' => [],
        'social_links' => array_combine(array_column($types, 'value'), $links)
    ]
];
print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [primary] => Array (
        [address_details] => Array ( )
        [contact_details] => Array ( )
        [social_links] => Array (
            [facebook] => Array (
                [type_id] => 1
                [url] =>
            )
            [twitter] => Array (
                [type_id] => 2
                [url] =>
            )
        )
    ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/S03t1)

**Update**

Based on the edit to OPs question, things get a lot more complicated to give a one-line solution. This should work:

```
$data = [
    'primary' => [
        'address_details' => [],
        'contact_details' => [],
        'social_links' => array_map(function ($v) use ($links) { return $links[array_search($v, array_column($links, 'type_id'))]; }, array_column($types, 'id', 'value'))
    ]
];
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BHjoK)

Comment: My mistake on my example, but the `$types['value']` would be the key, but I select the `$type` using it's **id**, updated my example. Can your code above be adapted to work still?

Comment: @MartynBall so the `id` value from `$types` is supposed to match the `type_id` value from `$links`?

Comment: @MartynBall I've added an update to my answer. It's a bit messy but is still a one-liner...

Answer (score 3):

A simple `for` loop can do it:

https://3v4l.org/h47MG

```
<?php

$links = [
    [
        'type_id' => '1',
        'url' => ''
    ],
    [
        'type_id' => '2',
        'url' => ''
    ]
];
$types = [
    [
        'value' => 'facebook'
    ],
    [
        'value' => 'twitter'
    ]
];
$result = [];
for($i = 0, $len = count($types); $i < $len; $i++) {
    $result[$types[$i]['value']] = $links[$i];
}
$data = [
    'primary' => [
        'address_details' => [],
        'contact_details' => [],
        'social_links' => $result
    ]
];

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing a loop outside of the `$data` array you see. As I need to do this a couple of times and it looks messy.

Comment: @AdamWhateverson I don't understand what you mean. It creates a new $result array and adds a new key(value from $types) => value(entry from $links) to the $result array. $result[] = .. would add them without key (i.e. zero, one... indexed) which is not what OP wrote in his example output

Comment: @Xatenev Hello, ignore me, I read the code wrong, it's fine :) Weird how you get down voted here just for trying to have a chat. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a loop to modify the array directly :

```
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($links); $i++) {
    $links[$types[$i]['value']] = $links[$i];
    unset($links[$i]);
}

var_dump($links);
```

Output :

```
["facebook"]=> array(2) { 
    ["type_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["url"]=> string(0) "" 
} 
["twitter"]=> array(2) { 
    ["type_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["url"]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

Or by using [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) if you do not want a loop, per your comment on another answer :

```
array_combine(array_column($types, 'value'), $links)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<pre><code>
$social_links = [];
foreach ($types as $type):
    $social_links[$type['value']] = $links[$key];
endforeach;

$data = [
    'primary' => [
        'address_details' => [],
        'contact_details' => [],
        'social_links' => $social_links
    ]
];

print_r($data);
</code></pre>
```